Conda env doesn't work - where python/conda returns nothing
I cannot seem to get my conda environment working in PyCharm. So I reinstalled Windows to make sure I get it right. Yet, the problem persists.
I installed Python, added to path. Installed PyCharm. Installed Miniconda, did not add to path, because that was recommended. I made a virtual env using conda in PyCharm. Did pip install -r requirements. But when I run the file, it doesn't recognize Flask. How? Why? It's installed, I checked. Not only are my pip installs not recognized, but my local modules aren't recognized either.
I tried adding conda (C:\Users\Tamara\miniconda3) path to user and system env variables, but without any luck.
I tried making new environments, changing interpreters, nothing works. Somehow I even managed to get all the downloaded modules like Flask working, but I never managed to get it to recognize local modules.
Conda and Python are obviously both installed, but where conda and where python return nothing.
I just want to conda create and activate environment, install my requirements in it via pip and run the code. Even though I managed to create and activate an env, and install requirements, modules are not recognized and where conda/python doesn't return anything.
Any help is super appreciated!
(v2) PS C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion-bot> conda --version

conda 24.9.2

(v2) PS C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion-bot> where conda

(v2) PS C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion-bot> python --version

Python 3.12.7

(v2) PS C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion-bot> where python

(v2) PS C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion-bot> py .\notion_bot\slack_app\app.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Tamara\Python\notion_bot\slack_app\app.py", line 3, in <module>

from flask import Flask

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'



Your example shows two version numbers and an error. But it doesn't show where your system seems to think Python and Conda are installed, nor does it show whether your environment is activated, whether that environment has in fact flask (or anything) installed. You also tell us nothing about how you configured PyCharm (or at least how you got it to use Conda for your project). There is not enough information here to even start helping you.
